# How to do an animation in Javascript with pause and play options?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function animate(elem,style,from,to,time) {
    if (!elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
        elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from))+'px';
        if (step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 25);
    elem.style[style] = from + 'px';
}
```

Here is my code. and i need to pause and play in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer

```
function animate(elem,style,to,time,callback)
{
if(!elem) return;

_animating = true;

curAnimElem = elem;  /*stores the current Element*/
curStyle = style;    /*stores the current style*/
curTo = to;          /*stores the current to 'px'*/
curCallback = callback;  /*stores the current callbak function*/

    if(style === 'left'){ from = elem.offsetLeft; }
else if(style === 'top'){ from = elem.offsetTop; }

var start = new Date().getTime(),
animTimer = setInterval(function()
{
    if(!pauseV)
    {
        pauseTime = Math.round(time - (new Date().getTime()-start));
        var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
        elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+'px';         
        if( step == 1 ){ _animating = false; clearInterval(animTimer);    if(callback){callback(); callback = null;} }
    }
    else{clearInterval(animTimer);}
},25);
elem.style[style] = from + 'px';
}
```

the above code is to animate the elements(left or top only). to **PAUSE** and **PLAY**, include the below code in pause/play event function.

```
function pauseFun()
{   
    if(pauseV)
    {   
        pauseV = false;
        if(_animating){ animate(curAnimElem,curStyle,curTo,pauseTime,curCallback); }
    }
   else if(!pauseV)
  {pauseV = true;}
}
```

Its works for me......
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var doAnimation=true;
var timer=0;
var start=undefined;

function animate(elem,style,from,to,time)
 {
  if(!elem && doAnimation) return;  
     if(start==undefined)start = new Date().getTime();          
     timer = setInterval(function(){         
         var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);                  
         elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+'px';         
        if( step == 1){ 
            doAnimation=false;
            clearInterval(timer);
            elem.style[style] = from+'px';
            start=undefined;
        }},25);

  }


function fun(){        
    doAnimation=!doAnimation;    
    if(doAnimation){play();}
    else{pause();}  
}

function play(){          
     animate( document.getElementById('box'),'left',0 , 200, 7000);
}

function pause(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    play();
});
```

Check out the fiddle here:
    http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/V9MHN/1/

Comment: pls check this. [JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xB4Kt/1/). i seems to be not working.

Comment: check my updated answer... also the fiddle is there just in case you a need a working sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use `clearInterval(timer)` to pause the animation and then `timer = setInterval(...)` again to resume it. You would need to break the `setInterval` callback out into its own named function (inside the body of the first function) to make resuming easier.